# how can i auto reload on vs code on edge browser or firefox?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As of now my default browser is Edge and Whenever I open any html file on edge using live server extension on vs code, it do not auto reload on browser... same with Firefox. I tried changing to Firefox and same thing happened there as well. How to fix this?
here the json file if this helps

```
    {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "liveServer.settings.useWebExt": true,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
    },
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": null,
    "auto-rename-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
        
        
        "*"
    ],
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "phpformatter.composer": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify",
    "liveServer.settings.fullReload": true,
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "microsoft-edge",
    //"editor.renameOnType": true
}
```

Comment: I have edge as default like you and using live server. no problem for me. consider adding more detail please.

Comment: If you double click on an HTML file it won't reload it for you, you have to go to vscode, go to "File" at the top left corner and press open folder and open the folder you have your html file, then at the bottom right part of your screen you will see "Go Live". If you press that your project will open in a new tab. Did you do all that?

Comment: @Costa yes, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Go To extension tab on vs code download "live server"
and use live server extension for auto reload in any browser like edge, chrome and if its dose not work comment again i will reply your answer.

Comment: sir i already have live server installed and now i updated my question with json file